# Get objects from list in Linq to new list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am trying to test if a question exists in a control and then selecting the question text to add to a list.

I have a list of 20 questions. Only 7 are visible on the screen. I want to get the objects from a list that correspond to the values of the items

```
  public partial class CustomQuestion
  {

    public string QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string ParentQuestionID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionOrder { get; set; }
    public string ShowOn { get; set; }
    public string Option0 { get; set; }
    public string Option1 { get; set; }
    public string SelectedOption;
  }

 public partial class MultipleChoiceQuestion : UserControl
 {
      public string Answer { get; set; }

      public string Question { get; set; }
 }


 public partial class Form1
 {
    private List<CustomQuestion> MyQuestion = new List<CustomQuestion>();



    private void FindObjects()
    {
   var mylist =  MyQuestion.
      Where(qq => qq.Question == FlowLayouPanel1.Controls.Cast<Control>().
                Where(x => x is MultipleChoiceQuestion).Cast<MultipleChoiceQuestion>().
                    Select(c => c.Question));
    }
 }
```

The error I get is :

```
      Error 1   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>
```

I hope this is clear enough to demonstrate what I am trying to do. If you have any questions or points I can clarify, let me know.

Comment: Well, you are comparing `qq.Question` that is string with list of strings that returned by last `Select(c => c.Question)`, and they can't be compared. Maybe you need to use `Any` on `Select` result?

Comment: You should be using OfType<T> instead of doing a series of casts and wheres.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov do you happen to know where the Any should go? I think thats the answer also but I havent used any before

Comment: your right @Servy , when I copied and pasted the error and it posted the file and directory and all that crap so I erased a little to far. Sorry about that, thanks.

Comment: @CalvinSmith Again, when you look at the whole error message it should be crystal clear what's wrong.  Just read the message; it explains the problem *exactly*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to compare a single question to a set of questions. You need to do an intersection.

To avoid re-constructing the list of questions in your controls 20 times, first populate a list with the questions in your controls:

```
var controlQuestions = FlowLayouPanel1.Controls
                                      .OfType<MultipleChoiceQuestion>()
                                      .Select(c => c.Question)
                                      .ToList();
```

Then do the intersection:

```
var mylist = MyQuestion.Where(q => controlQuestions.Contains(q));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write like this:

```
var mylist =  MyQuestion.
  Where(qq => FlowLayouPanel1.Controls.OfType<MultipleChoiceQuestion>().
                Select(c => c.Question).Any(c => qq.Question == c));
```

Then it will return all question that exists in both `MyQuestion` and

```
FlowLayouPanel1.Controls
    .OfType<MultipleChoiceQuestion>()
    .Select(c => c.Question)
```

But it may depends on what you want to achieve

The problem with your original code was that you were trying to compare one `qq.Question` that is `string` type with `List<string>` that returned by right expression. But i suppose you need to check if right expression contains left string, so my answer is a sample how to make it

Comment: PS: i admit that @JLRishe approach is better as in that case for each question list of questions from controls will be created, that is a bit waste of resources.